# Using Views without Database Support

Tags: views, database, 8, files

We build a Drupal 8 based content management system that uses a triple store as the main data back-end. So we don't have any content data in Database tables. All CRUD operations on entities stored there work fine.
BUT: Views integration seems to be much harder (or even impossible?). As views - and especially Drupal\views\EntityViewsData heavily relies on database tables it is not obvious how to provide the Views module with the required information without having to mirror everything in the local DB.
So, the question in short:
**Will Views work without a DB?**
 And - if yes - what classes will we have to implement to achieve that.

Comment: I highly doubt it, since Views probably uses function [db_query()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21database.inc/function/db_query/8)

Comment: It used to be possible in D7, by extending `views_plugin_query`. Fago used it for creating Picasa photo albums on the fly ([sandbox](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/fago/1493180)). In D8 there are [Views query plugins](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!src!Plugin!views!query!QueryPluginBase.php/group/views_query_plugins/8), so I suppose you should be able to extend on `QueryPluginBase`. But I highly doubt there are any 'in the wild' example of it yet.

Comment: You could try to mirror your data in database tables.